# Application has stopped immediately after starting on Android

Tags: c#, android, mono

I am designing a simple webBrowser with webview, in VS 2010, when I compile program, it's okay, and even when I run it in emulator it works all right and I see the window and button, but when I install on device, immediately says 'stopped' and closes the application without showing anything.

I use API 8 to compile and install unsigned version and try to install it on android 4 or higher.

Appendix: When I run project in xamarin, it doesn't create apk file, nevertheless I did all configuration said in docummention.

What should I do to run on device or when can I compile it for once?

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat. That will tell us exactly where the error is.

Comment: I doubt that was a "Network on main thread" exception. Post the stack trace please.